# JavaFX: How to stretch a label inside of a TableColumnCell?

Tags: javafx, label, tableview

I'm filling up a TableView with labels, but the labels are only as big as the text. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR3a0.jpg).

Is there any way to bind the width and height of the label to the size of the table cell?

I've already tried

```
label.minWidthProperty().bind(column.minWidthProperty());
```

but that does not work.

Comment: try something like: `label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot :)